# Prism 6 Login/ Logout sequence

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, prism, logout

Application has a login with several possible roles.
Regular user logs in and logs out.(At this level if modules are loaded on demand than only User module is loaded)
Admin logs in and logs out. (At this moment both admin and user modules are loaded).

Is is safe to have multiple modules loaded, even if not navigated, or is there a way to "unload" or uninitialize the modules, or possibly re init the whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to have multiple modules loaded even if you don't navigate to them.  There is no "unload". You could use the IEventAggregator to notify of your "unload" event to remove views or clean up portions of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, however if it is safe, what is the point of the "Loading Modules Based on Roles" then?

Comment: Some people inject views in the IModule.Initialize method. If you have an Admin module, you only want admins getting the functionality injected. So you only load the Admin module if the user is an Admin.  Another approach it to not load anything when the module initializes and use eventing instead